# Запятая в предложении из букваря

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Предложение из букваря:
**А это потому, что мама зимой ничего не ест и молока у неё мало.**

Считаю, что перед "и молока" должна быть запятая, так как "А потому" относится только ко второй основе, которая является следствием первой.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsY23.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

**А это потому, что мама зимой ничего не ест и молока у неё мало.**

Это однородные придаточные причины, связанные одиночным союзом И, **поэтому запятая не ставится.**

Союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО  **общий** для двух придаточных, причем он расчленен запятой (его местоименная часть принадлежит главной части сложноподчиненного предложения).

Comment: Смущает тот момент, что союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО по смыслу не общий, а относится только к МАЛО МОЛОКА, что является следствием плохого питания. Например, можно заменить И МОЛОКА на И ПОЭТОМУ МОЛОКА - тогда запятая, получается, нужна?

Comment: Придаточные предложения связаны по смыслу общим наречием "зимой",  поэтому совместно обозначают причину. Соответственно,  причинный союз относится к ним обоим, и с букварем всё нормально.  Интонационно оба придаточных образуют единую фразу, пауза не делается.

Comment: "А это потому, что молока у мамы зимой мало." - имеет смысл. "А это потому, что мама зимой ничего не ест." - не объясняет размер медвежат. "Мама зимой ничего не ест, и поэтому молока у неё мало." - имеет смысл. И и И ПОЭТОМУ в данном случае имеют одинаковый смысл, при этом во втором случае запятая ставится однозначно.

Comment: Со смыслом всё ясно, здесь нужно говорить о грамматике предложения. Рассмотрим сложносочиненное предложение: Мама зимой ничего не ест и молока у неё мало. Наречие "зимой" - ОБЩИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ, в этом случае запятая в ССП не ставится. Это Розенталь: Крылья у гуся были растопырены и клюв раскрыт (Ч.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  А теперь перейдем к СПП с однородными придаточными. Почему между ними при наличии союза И не ставится запятая? Да потому что они относятся к одному главному придаточному и поэтому связаны между собой.

Comment: В нашем случае  однородность не очевидна  (она проявляется через причинно-следственные отношения), но зато связь однозначно обозначена общим наречием. Отсюда следует  вывод: запятую не ставим.